# In general, should a custom initialize() be executed before or after super.initState()?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

Should my custom `initialize()` run before or after `super.initState()`? Or does it not matter?

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialize();
  }
```

OR

```
@override
  void initState() {
    initialize();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: I think the canonical answer would be to call `super.initState()` first, so that when your subclass's `initialize()` runs, the parent class is initialized. But I'm sure there are specific situations where you might have to do it the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) of `initState` method:

> Implementations of this method should start with a call to the inherited method, as in super.initState().

So the answer is that you have to call it first. The reason in my opinion is that the inherited method is responsible for basic initialisation when the widget is inserted into to widget tree, so calling your code before `super.initState()` could result in undesired behaviour.